# NMocks2 Argument Syntax in Rhino Mocks?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

In NMocks2 you can mock up the result of a method you don't know the arguments to before hand using

```
Stub.On(aMock)
    .Method( ... )
    .WithAnyArguments()
    .Will(Return.Value( ... );
```

from [NMocks2 Cheatsheet](http://www.nmock.org/cheatsheet.html).  My question is, is there a similar mechanism for Rhino mocks when you don't care about the arguments?  I want to make a call similar to:

```
    object objectIDontWantToRecreate = null; // Won't be null in actuality
    object alwaysReturned = ...;
    Expect.Call(mockObject.Method(objectIDontWantToRecreate)).Return(alwaysReturned);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There sure is:

```
Expect.Call(mockObject.Method(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(alwaysReturn)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Don't know how I missed it.  I guess there's a bunch of stuff to learn here :)

Comment: Rhino is a really flexible framework, but the learning curve is steep.  If you're dealing with .Net 3.5, I would highly recommend Moq over Rhino.